# JavaFx GetChildern() function not avalible

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I can't find getChildren() element in Javafx to add a button or a text in a container.
I tried to search for a class but i dindn't find any solution for this problem
any solution?

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.*;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Group root = new Group();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        Text txt = new Text("Mohanned");
        root.getChildren().add(txt);
        txt.setY(50);
        root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().add(txt);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The method is not `public` in `Parent` (made `public` in `Pane` and `Group`). You cannot declare 2 variables with the same name either.

Answer (score 2):

getChildren() has protected acces in Parent. See

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getChildren--

for more information.

Also there is a problem, in

```
Group root = new Group();
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

You can't have two variables with the same name in the same scope; the compiler won't know which variable you are reffering to.